# Compare one table with another in mysql and display matched record

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have two mysql tabales.

```
Table1:opened_datatable
Table2:unidata
```

Table1 has only one column:`Emails`
Table2 has 45 columns, three of them are:`Email_Office`, `Email_Personal1`, `Email_Personal2`

I want to fetch full rows from `Table2-unidata` if `Emails` column of `Table1` matches with either `Email_Office` or `Email_Personal1` or `Email_Personal2`. I am getting little bit confused here.I tried this way:

```
select a.emails 
from opened_datatable a
where a.Emails in (select * 
                   from unidata b 
                   where b.email_office=a.emails 
                      or b.Email_Personal1=a.emails 
                      or b.Email_Personal2=a.Emails
                   )
```

Its showing only one row of first table while I want to show matched rows of `Table2 -unidata`.  First I need to mention table 2 and then I should have to match it with table 1-`opened_datatable`. But how can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try This:

```
SELECT a.emails, b.* 
FROM opened_datatable a
INNER JOIN unidata b ON a.emails IN (b.email_office, b.Email_Personal1, b.Email_Personal2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your current query should return an error.

Try a Corrrelated Subquery using EXISTS, quite similar to your apporach:

```
select a.emails 
from opened_datatable a
where EXISTS 
 ( select * 
   from unidata b 
   where b.email_office=a.emails 
      or b.Email_Personal1=a.emails 
      or b.Email_Personal2=a.Emails
 )
```

You will probably not get good performance due to the `OR`-ed conditions.

Edit:

If performance is too bad, you might try a UNION approach:

```
select a.emails 
from opened_datatable a
where a.emails 
IN
 ( select email_office 
   from unidata b 
   UNION
   select Email_Personal1 
   from unidata b 
   UNION
   select b.Email_Personal2 
   from unidata b 
 )
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. No my current query did not give an error. Let me try your query.

Comment: I've tried your query but its still running since last 15 minutes. I have a huge database of 10 lac data. I keep experiment on it, takes time so many times but not these much